# JS creating new options with loop

Tags: javascript

Help needed on a simple task, tried couple different ways, but looks like I'm missing something on both. I want to create a drop-down menu with number of years. Here is my attempts so far, Nr1:

```
function selectOne(){
        var select - document.getElementById('year')
        for(var i=1950;i<1960;++i){
            var option = document.createElement('option');
            option.text = option.value = i;
            select.add(option, 0);
        }
    }
```

and heres nr2:

```
function selectOne(){
        for(var i=1950;i<1960;++i){
            var yearList = 1950;
            var whichYear = new Option();
            whichYear.text = yearList[i];
            whichYear.value = yearList[i];
            document.forms[0].year.options[i] = whichYear;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first function has a typo 'var select -' but apart from that it seems to be ok

```
function selectOne(){
    var select = document.getElementById('year')
    for(var i=1950;i<1960;++i){
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        option.text = option.value = i;
        select.add(option, 0);
    }
}
```

Assuming you have

```
<select id="year"></select>
```

and call the function correctly it should print out a dropdown with values from 1950 to 1959

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
<select id = "year"></select>   
<script type = "text/javascript">
function selectOne(){
    var select = document.getElementById('year')
    for(var i=1950;i<=1960;i++){
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        option.text = option.value = i;
        select.appendChild(option, 0);
    }
}

selectOne();
</script>
```